# save all the xml parsing in Dict with Python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I would like to save all the content in my dict. I can catch almost everything except the last items.

My python's code look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xml.sax

class MovieHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.item = {}
      self.CurrentData = ""
      self.type = ""
      self.format = ""
      self.year = ""
      self.rating = ""
      self.stars = ""
      self.description = ""

   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):     
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "movie":
         #if self.item:
         print self.item
         print "*****Movie*****"
         title = attributes["title"]
         print "Title:", title

   # Call when an elements ends
   def endElement(self, tag):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         self.item["type"] = self.type
         #print "Type:", self.type
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         self.item["format"] = self.format
         #print "Format:", self.format
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         self.item["year"] = self.year
         #print "Year:", self.year
      elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
         self.item["rating"] = self.rating
         #print "Rating:", self.rating
      elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
         self.item["stars"] = self.stars
         #print "Stars:", self.stars
      elif self.CurrentData == "description":
         self.item["description"] = self.description
         #print "Description:", self.description
      self.CurrentData = ""

   # Call when a character is read
   def characters(self, content):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         self.type = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         self.format = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         self.year = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
         self.rating = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
         self.stars = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "description":
         self.description = content

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):

   # create an XMLReader
   parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
   # turn off namepsaces
   parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

   # override the default ContextHandler
   Handler = MovieHandler()
   parser.setContentHandler( Handler )

   parser.parse("movies.xml")
```

My xml file look like this:

```
<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
<movie title="Enemy Behind">
   <type>War, Thriller</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
 self.date = ""   <year>2003</year>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>
</movie>
<movie title="Transformers">
   <type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>1989</year>
   <rating>R</rating>
   <stars>8</stars>
   <description>A schientific fiction</description>
</movie>
   <movie title="Trigun">
   <type>Anime, Action</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <episodes>4</episodes>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Vash the Stampede!</description>
   </movie>
<movie title="Ishtar">
   <type><![CDATA[Neuilly-sur-Seine]]></type>
   <format>VHS</format>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>2</stars>
   <description>Viewable boredom</description>
</movie>
</collection>
```

At the last tag, I have no information.

How I can solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should start by saying what the expected output would look like?  It's quite possible that you'd be better off using a different type of parser (e.g. `xml.etree.ElementTree`)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem is simplified if you use `ElementTree`.  For example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(s)  # s is a string with the xml data.
movies = tree.iter('movie')
dct = {}
for element in movies:
  dct[element.attrib['title']] = element
print dct  # {'Transformers': <Element 'movie' at 0x7f8f40d6e750>, 'Ishtar': <Element 'movie' at 0x7f8f40d6eb50>, 'Enemy Behind': <Element 'movie' at 0x7f8f40d6e2d0>, 'Trigun': <Element 'movie' at 0x7f8f40d6e990>}
print {element.tag: element.text for element in dct['Transformers']}  # {'rating': 'R', 'description': 'A schientific fiction', 'format': 'DVD', 'stars': '8', 'year': '1989', 'type': 'Anime, Science Fiction'}
```

From here, hopefully it's not too difficult to modify to suite your needs...

Note that `sax` really shines when you have huge files that you need to parse iteratively.  If you want to store all the data at once, then usually `ElementTree` makes things easier.